How to slice a 2D python list to change multiple values vertically and horizontally
I'm making a battleships game using Python. In this game, I create two 10x10 grids using the following code:
  def __init__(self, oceaan = 10, radar = 10):

        self.radar = [[0 for y in range(radar)] for x in range (radar)]
        self.oceaan = [[0 for y in range(oceaan)] for x in range (oceaan)]

This code replaces the value 0 at the first index of the first row with a 1:
self.oceaan[0][0] = 1

However, my ships all have a size between 2 and 5 and should be able to be placed both horizontally and vertically. As such, I tried several solutions:
This raises TypeError: can only assign an iterable. I don't know why this happens. Could someone explain why?
self.oceaan[0][0:5] = 1

This code seems to replace all the values at index 0 to 4 in the first row with a singular 1:
self.oceaan[0][0:5] = [1]

This code yields the intended result for a ship with length 5:
self.oceaan[0][0:5] = [1]*5

However, this only tackles the horizontal placement. I would also like to place them vertically.
I though it would be as simple as this:
self.oceaan[0:5][0] = [1]*5

However, this simply returns the 10x10 grid with every value still set to 0.
How could I change my code to allow for vertical placement in a way similar to my solution for horizontal placement?

You can't, you will need to use a for loop to operate over all indices, or use a 2-dimensional array like numpy provides.

Could you elaborate on how to use a for loop or numpy arrays and show code?
